# C# refactoring polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism, refactoring

As far as I know, polymorphism is related to class inheritance. Something like this:

```
class NormalCardStatus : ICardStatus {

    void DoStuff(Card card) {
        // ...
    }
}

class UnderwaterCardStatus : ICardStatus {

    void DoStuff(Card card) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In a C# refactoring [book by Martin Fowler](http://www.cs.umss.edu.bo/doc/material/mat_gral_137/M.Fowler%20et%20al%20-%20Refactoring%20-%20Improving%20the%20Design%20of%20Existing.pdf) on page 35 it is suggested to replace Conditional Logic of another class with Polymorphism. However, in the suggested solution I do not see any inheritance. What kind of polymorphism is that?

Comment: You should finish reading the chapter first, as on page 38+ it is explained.

Answer (score 1):

> polymorphism is related to class inheritance

That is true. A lot of things in OOP are related to class inheritance though, so knowing the above may not really help much.

I'm not familiar with the book you're using, but I think it's not hard to explain the concept of replacing conditional logic with polymorphism.

Consider this example object:

```
class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void MakeSound()
    {
        switch (Name)
        {
        case "Dog":
            Bark();
            break;
        case "Cat":
            Meow();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void Bark() { /* bark implementation goes here */ }
    private void Meow() { /* meow implementation goes here */ }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Animal animal1 = new Animal("Dog"), animal2 = new Animal("Cat");

animal1.MakeSound(); // barks!
animal2.MakeSound(); // meows!
```

Note in the above, every time you call `MakeSound()`, the class has a *condition*. It checks the value of `Name`, and calls a different method depending on that value.

Polymorphism allows you to declare the basic behavior in a base class, but then delegate the *implementation* of that behavior in derived classes:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    protected Animal(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public abstract void MakeSound();
}

class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog() : base("Dog") { }

    public override void MakeSound() { Bark(); }

    private void Bark() { /* bark implementation goes here */ }
}

class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat() : base("Cat") { }

    public override void MakeSound() { Meow(); }

    private void Meow() { /* meow implementation goes here */ }
}
```

Used like this:

```
Animal animal1 = new Dog(), animal2 = new Cat();

animal1.MakeSound(); // barks!
animal2.MakeSound(); // meows!
```

Note that here, we decide when the object is created what kind of object it is, same as before, but this is expressed as the *type* of the object now, instead of just a string that is passed to the constructor.

Then we can still operate with the object as `Animal`, and still receive different behaviors depending on which object kind we originally created, but the behavior is automatically directed to the appropriate implementation based on the object type, rather than a runtime comparison on some property value.

Of course, now that I type all the above, it occurs to me that there may already be a similar discussion on Stack Overflow explaining all of this. If someone else wants to try to look that up, I don't mind. But in the meantime, I hope the above helps.